# using awk command to get the correct name

Tags: awk

I want to get the filename from a long string in shell script.After reading some example from [likegeeks.com](https://likegeeks.com/awk-command/),I write a simple solution:

```
#/bin/bash

cdnurl="http://download.example.com.cn/download/product/vpn/rules/vpn_patch_20190218162130_sign.pkg?wsSecret=9cadeddedfr7bb85a20a064510cd3f353&wsABSTime=5c6ea1e7"
echo ${cndurl}

url=`echo ${cdnurl} | awk -F'/' '{ print $NF }'`
result=`echo ${url} | awk -F '?' '{ print $1}'`
echo ${url}

echo ${result}
```

I just want to get vpn_patch_20190218162130_sign.pkg,and the it does.I wonder is there any smart ways (may be one line).

If behind pkg it's not ?,how to use pkg to get the filename,I am not sure if always ? after pkg,but the filename always be *.pkg.

Comment: try `echo "$cdnurl"|awk -vFS=[?/] '{print $(NF-1)}'`

Comment: @PS. wonderful!thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try : this is more robust as compare to second `awk` command:

```
echo "$cdnurl"|awk -v FS='/' '{gsub(/?.*/,"",$NF);print $NF}'
vpn_patch_20190218162130_sign.pkg

#less robust
echo "$cdnurl"|awk -vFS=[?/] '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

You should use `sed` :

```
sed -r 's|.*/(.*.pkg).*|\1|g'
```

Comment: If behind pkg it's not ?,how to use pkg to get the filename,I am not sure if always ? after pkg.

Comment: @J.Doe can you add example URL where there in no `?`  ?

Comment: `-v FS`  == `-F`

Comment: @PS. http://download.example.com.cn/download/product/vpn/rules/vpn_patch_20190218162130_sign.pkgdwsSecret=9cadeddedfr7bb85a20a064510cd3f353&wsABSTime=5c6ea1e7,maybe use _sign.pkg to get the name ,but the wsSecrt may get the same value,it struck me.

Comment: @J.Doe you should try `sed -r 's|.*/(.*.pkg).*|\1|g'`

Comment: @PS.  thanks for your answer,I use echo "$cdnurl"|awk -v FS='/' '{gsub(/?.*/,"",$NF);print $NF}',someday it gives a error msg:awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)
?.*

Comment: @PS. sed -r 's|.*/(.*.pkg).*|\1|g' this now works well.